# How to join with a table where the date contains hours

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a main table called MachineData, where each row is a session with a distinct sessionid and the start time of that sessionId (with hours included). It also includes information on if the session was successful or not.

What I want to do, is count by week how many successful sessions we have had, and to do this I understand that I have to create a calendar table.

I have created one the following way.

```
MyDateTable = CALENDAR(MIN(MachineData[StartTime]), MAX(MachineData[StartTime]))
```

My question is, how do I join MyDateTable and MachineData? Obviously MachineData has dates with time on them, and MyDateTable also contains time, but its always midnight, which means that there won't be a match with MachineData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I join MyDateTable and MachineData?

Add a column to MachineData that is just the Date and join on that.